# Defect detection with pattern variation in comparison to template

Tags: image-processing, template-matching

I am trying to detect defects on wafer images comparing them to a reference template. as the images are proprietary, I made sample images that can illustrate the problem.
The sample images should be the result of noise reduction, Filter curvature fit, and binarization. with these steps I mostly have no problem except with the noise reduction but this is not our point here.
The problem lies in the defect detection step. I used image difference but due to the pattern variations and different line thickness it results in too many false positives. I tried statistical modeling where I divided the reference image to small sections, fit each section to distribution (in my case I used weibul) and made the same with the defect image and compared them. It was able to detect big defects (like the missing rectangle in the middle) but with smaller ones it didn't.
any Ideas or directions on how to proceed?

[image: Reference Template Image]
Reference Image

[image: Defect Image]
Defect Image

Comment: from what I see the main difference is line thickness and shape, so why not compare these features vs some OK reference? correlation based template matching should give good results as well.

Comment: This diagram is really insufficient. Can't you post just image fragments ? (Original images, please.)

Comment: @Piglet , you are right, the difference is in line thickness and shape. The objects with only line thickness difference are not considered as defects. only the parts that I have marked with Red here. I know I can get the different objects in shape, but with the different line thickness, when I compare them I get other false positives resulting from different line thickness.so the question is there a way to overcome that?

Comment: @YvesDaoust , as I said I can not post original images. The upper image is the reference here and the lower is the defect image with the red marked parts as the defects to be detected.

Comment: @Salama: I expected such an answer. Can't help. Answering image processing questions without seeing samples is always counterproductive. Always.